# Add space item decoration for sections

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I made a recyclerview with search results divided by its type:
header, items and footer. What I need is to add spaces between these sections (like in cards), preferably not by additional views.

[image]

I tried to add decoration to header itself, but it gets wrong margin

```
class SpaceHeaderDecoration(private val space: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    ...

    val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
    val viewType = parent.adapter.getItemViewType(position)
    if (viewType == Adapter.HEADER) {
        outRect.top = space
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In what way is your current code not working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [DividerItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration)?:

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(
  recyclerView.getContext(),
  layoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerDecoration);
```